# Using subpath imports in React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native

Is it possible to use subpath imports in React Native?

I have the following `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "imports": {
        "#utils/*": "./src/utils/*",
    }
}
```

and am trying to use them as follows:

```
import {someUtility} from '#utils/someUtility.js';
```

with the following in the file `./src/utils/someUtility.js`:

```
export const someUtility = 'utility';
```

but receive the following error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module #utils/someUtility from "${CURRENT_PATH}". #utils/someUtility could not be found within the project.
```